# How to disable form submit of the done button of iPhone keyboards?

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications

I just want to know the right way to disable the "done" button of iPhone keyboards. I'm building a mobile webapp for iPhone. Thanks.

Comment: You would get a more helpful response if you show your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from submit preventative code from `jQuery` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        $("form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
}
```

also you can mix this with `.keyup();` if you need to only disable `done` key.